# google maps and exact location

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to show maps in my application. i have followed number of tutorials and took help from many websites. sometimes grids are shown but the map doesn't show up, and other times it gives me errors. i searched about this so it was been said in number of places that API key is wrong, but i followed exact tutorials and got a key. i don't have any idea why the map isn't showing up. please guide me.

Ok so here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD6acBVex9ULfMB4U3DVl240hFMPjJA3hk"/>

</manifest>
```

It just shows me grids.

Comment: Yes, please post your code. It's not possible to help otherwise.

Comment: Please enlist and post all your practical issues and problems here. We will not be able help you until and unless you precisely describe what errors or issues you are facing.

Comment: i have posted my code.. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You have two keys: yours and debug. The debug key shows maps only you have device on test mode, your key only shows maps if you create a apk file and install on device.